# Remover required javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un `form` en `php` que tiene dos **`input`** radio. Al seleccionar uno, muestra el otro y oculta un `div`. Lo que pretendo es que  cuando esté oculto este `div`, el **`required`** este deshabilitado. Lo estoy intentando hace horas, pero como no tengo experiencia con `JavaScript` mi código no esta funcionando en la parte de retirar el **`required`**.

Podrían ayudarme con esto?

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var valor = $(event.target).val();
    if(valor =="1"){
      $("#hospedagem").show( );
    } else if (valor == "0") {
      $("#hospedagem").hide(
        function () {
          $('#nome_hotel').removeAttr("required");
        }
      );
    } else { 
        // Otra cosa
    }
  });
});
```

Código `html` donde están las `div's`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="requer_quarto" class="control-label" style="margin-right: 20px;">¿Precisa cadastrar hospedagem para a excurssão? </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="1" checked> SIM
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="0"> NÃO
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4" id="hospedagem">
  <label class="control-label">Hospedagem</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="nome_hotel" id="nome_hotel" class="form-control input-lg" required="required">
    <span class="field-explanation" style="font-size: 14px;">ex. Pousada recanto verde</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola revise tu código y solo te hace falta agregar la propiedad **`id="hospedagem"`** al **`div`**  que quieres ocultar.

Revisa el snnipet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
    var valor = $(event.target).val();
    console.log(valor)
    if(valor == 1) {
        $("#hospedagem").show( );
    } else if (valor == 0) {
        $("#hospedagem").hide(
          function () {
             $('#nome_hotel').removeAttr("required");
             $("#nome_hotel").prop('required',false);
          });

    } else { 
        // Otra cosa
    }
  });
});

$("#botonEnviar").on('click',function(){

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form id="pago">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="requer_quarto" class="control-label" style="margin-right: 20px;">¿Precisa cadastrar hospedagem para a excurssão? </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="1" checked> SIM
       </label>

       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="requer_quarto" name="requer_quarto" value="0"> NÃO
        </label>
</div>
<br>
<label class="control-label">Hospedagem</label>
   <div id="hospedagem">
     <input type="text" name="nome_hotel" id="nome_hotel" class="form-control input-lg" required>
      <span class="field-explanation" style="font-size: 14px;">ex. Pousada recanto verde
      </span>
   </div>
   <br>

    <input type="submit" id="botonEnviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Consegui dela forma que indicastes, muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides, marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios.